# Show function not working. Can't retrieve element by id. Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, database, model, controller, show

I have created resource controllers, one per model in my laravel 5.8 project. I want the show function to return the DB element i want based on the id inserted on the URL, as it is supposed to do. For now i do tests directly on my controller, i'm not using the "thisCircuit" function of my model. Calling the index, returns a json with all circuits. Calling the show returns nothing. How can i fix it?

**Show function**

```
    public function show(circuits $circuits)
    {
        $circuits = circuits::findOrFail($circuits);
        dd($circuits);
    }
```

**Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


class circuits extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'circuitId', 'circuitRef', 'name',
        'location', 'country', 'lat',
        'lng', 'alt', 'url',
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = 'circuitId';

    

    public function races()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\races', 'circuitId');
    }

    public function allCircuits(){
        $data = Circuits::all();
        return response()->json($data);
    }

    public function thisCircuit($id){
        $id = circuits::findOrFail($id);
    }
}
```

**Web.php File**

```
Route::get('/test', 'CircuitsController@index');
Route::get('/test/{circuit}', 'CircuitsController@show');
```

**URL on browser**

```
http://localhost:8000/test/1
```

**Result on browser**

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#947 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

Comment: You already get `$circuits` from the method parameter. (Might also want to rename your model to singular `Circuit`)

Comment: @brombeer is right, Laravel automatically handels this for you. This is called Route Model binding and can be found in the documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding
If you really don't want this to happen you can simply remove the variable type (so write only $circuits as parameter)

Comment: thank you. Removing the variable type solved it.

Comment: @GkChris99 May I ask why you are doing this and not using Route Model binding? 
With this you could simply remove  $circuits = circuits::findOrFail($circuits); in your code and have the same effect? :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's clean up this solution. A lot of smaller stylistic problems, that will hurt you going forward if not adjusted.

**Firstly**

Class names are starting with capitols letter in most standard naming conventions and in singular form.

```
circuits.php
```

Should be.

```
Circuit.php
```

---

**Secondly**

You are already using model binding. If you are doing this approach you can actually just return the circuit directly. As a bonus `Laravel` does not have to return response if the returned data is a model, unless you want to change the response code from 200 to something else.

```
public function show(Circuit $circuit) {
    return $circuit;
}
```

Also you are misunderstanding `firstOrFail()`. This code you have written can never return multiple Circuits, this will return a singular model.

```
$circuits = circuits::findOrFail($circuits);
```